# Problems Building a WCF Project with TFS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wcf, tfs, msbuild

I have a WCF project with a single .svc file and some .config files in it. I'm trying to create a build definition in TFS 2010 that will copy these files to an IIS folder on another machine.

I've done similar things with other MVC projects using the CopyDirectory task in the build XAML template. In those, I copy from the _PublishedWebsites folder to the IIS folder. However, with the WCF project, there is no _PublishedWebsites folder.

So I tried updating the MSBuild script for the WCF project to create a _PublishedWebsites folder and copy the files to it. This works when I build locally in Visual Studio 2010. But when it runs on the TFS build server, it doesn't quite work.

What I see there is that in "C:\Builds\1\PROJECT\PROJECT (Continuous Build)\Sources\PROJECT\bin\_PublishedWebsites", I can see all the files.

I'm guessing this "1 folder" is a temporary folder used for building...? I'm not sure what it's used for. But when I look at the actual drop location for the build, in "C:\Builds\PROJECT (Continuous Build)\PROJECT_BUILDNUMBER\", I see nothing except log files. None of the files from the "1 folder" are there.

Note that this same solution also has a WiX project to create a deployment package. That seems to build fine, and shows up in the drop location with no issue.

Answer (score 0):

`"1 folder" is a temporary folder used for building`
Yes. "1" is number of build agent(service that actually executes builds activities) on your build machine.

`But when I look at the actual drop location for the build, in "C:\Builds\PROJECT (Continuous Build)\PROJECT_BUILDNUMBER\", I see nothing except log files.`
 - Usually "Copy Files To Drop Location" flag is responsible for that.